# How to use an if condition for comparing strings in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a very small piece of code. And i am not sure where i am making it wrong. This is a simple IF condition, which should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

flag1=$1
flag2=$2

if [ "$flag1"="C" ] && [ "$flag2"="C" ]
then
echo "Proceed"

else
echo "Fail"

fi
```

I am running it using :- 
sh testif.sh C A
and 
sh testif.sh C C

And i am getting same result in both. 
Proceed

I am new to Unix Scripting. Please tell me what blunder i am doing.

Sorry, for asking such a basic question.

Comment: You need spaces around the `=` signs.

Comment: You are aware that `sh testif.sh` will override the shebang, forcing this to be interpreted as `sh` instead of `bash`?

Comment: No, what is that ? Can you give some info ?

Comment: The line `#!/bin/bash` defines the *default* interpreter for the script in question -- the interpreter used *if no interpreter is called explicitly* (e.g. when you'd be calling `./testif.sh` directly). When you're calling `sh testif.sh`, you are *specifying* `sh` to interpret the script. Now, most systems make `/usr/bin/sh` a link to `/bin/bash` -- but if invoked this way, bash will run in *compatibility mode*, mimicking original `sh` behaviour. Stuff like this can result in surprising errors -- for example, redirecting script output via `exec > >(tee logfile.txt)` will not work in `sh` mode.

Answer (score 4):

You want space in between your `bash` tokens:

```
if [ "$flag1" = "C" ] && [ "$flag2" = "C" ]
```

Comment: `=` is just fine, but you're right about the spaces.

Comment: @msfoster thanks, didn't realise the `=` operator is equivalent to `==` (just read from `man bash`).  Edited answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solved. Both = and == works fine. But this is really strange to use a space. What could be the reason for it ?

Comment: @TusharKesarwani Reason for space: `[` is an alias for `test` command executable, and the `test` program needs to see separate arguments.  The same reason `ls -al./somefile` won't work, neither will `test "a"="b"`.

Comment: @cerebriform Seems fair enough. Thanks a lot for your explaination

Comment: @TusharKesarwani The first thing `bash` does is to break your input line into tokens roughly seperated by white space, then it looks at those token to parse the line.  So you end up giveng `bash` the single token `"$flag1"="C"` which doesn't compute as a logical expression.

Comment: `=` and `==` are equivalent in bash, but `==` is a syntax error is some shells.

Comment: @cerebriform: The space is needed because of how bash parses _strings_ in general, and that `[` happens to be an external executable is incidental to the problem. Even with `[[` you'd need the spaces around the `=`, so that Bash doesn't parse the whole thing as a _single_ string [literal].

Comment: @cerebriform: Also note that `test` (and its alias `[`) is a shell _builtin_ in POSIX-like shells, even though it _also_ exists as an external utility (the parsing rules are the same, however).

Comment: `=` and `==` are only equivalent in the `[[` builtin, for `[` the `=` operator is strictly string equality. Compare: `[[ "bar" = *a* ]] && echo y` outputs "y" but `[ "bar" = *a* ] && echo y` outputs `bash: [: too many arguments` (depending on the contents of your current directory)

Answer (score 1):

[Paul Evans's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29033040/45375) has the proper solution: you need (at least) a *space* character around operators such as `=` (and its equivalent in bash, `==`).

As for **why you needed that space**:

Bash allows **string concatenation** simply by **placing tokens next to each other without whitespace** in between.
Whether the tokens are quoted or not, and what quotes are used is irrelevant; e.g.:

```
'ab'cd"ef"  # -> Bash sees: abcdef
```

In the case at hand:

```
"$flag1"="C" # Bash eventually sees: <value-of-$flag1>=C
```

In other words: `"$flag1"="C"` evaluates to a *single, nonempty* string *literal*, and applying `[ ... ]` to such a string *always* evaluates to true.

<sup>Generally, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128 in the POSIX shell spec. for information on how `[` and its alias `test` treat differing numbers of arguments (thanks, @glennjackman).</sup>

**For Bash to recognize the intended syntactic elements of `"$flag1"="C"` as such, you must therefore *separate the elements with at least one space each*.**: `"$flag1" = "C"`

---

If you want your **solution to be more `bash`-like**, however, **consider use of `[[ ... ]]`** rather than POSIX syntax `[ ... ]`:

```
if [[ $flag1 == "C" && $flag2 == "C" ]] # ...
```

Benefits:

- Allows you to use `&&` *inside* a *single* `[[ ... ]]` construct.
- Obviates the need to double-quote your variable references (though double-quoting never hurts and is actually important on the *right* side of `=` / `==` to distinguish string literals from patterns).
- Performs slightly better.

**Compatibility note**: While **`[[ ... ]]` works in `bash` and also `zsh` and `ksh`** (though the behavior differs subtly), it is NOT POSIX-compliant. In situations where that is a concern, stick with `[ ... ]`.

Comment: For your answer to be even better, you should talk about what `[` (and `test`) does when given different numbers of arguments. ([posix manual for `test`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128))

Comment: @glennjackman: Thanks for the tip, I've updated my answer accordingly.